# Right align a column in datagridview doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am having a `datagridiview` which is dynamically bound to a `datatable`. I would like to align some of the columns in header to right aligned.

I tried this setting for the `datagridview` for both cellstyle and headercell. For cell style it is showing correctly but for header it is not:

[image]

The code I used:

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns["Quantity"].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
this.dataGridView1.Columns["UnitPrice"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
```

Can some one help me?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The code *works*: the space you see at the right of the header text is "normal".

The `DataGridView` supports sorting by columns. Therefore, each column header reserves enough space to display the sort glyph (usually an arrow).

If you want the text in column header to be *perfectly* right aligned, you'll need to disable sorting. Set the `SortMode` property for the column to *NotSortable*. This will prevent space from being reserved for the sort glyph.

object lesson:

```
public class FrmTest : Form
{

    public FrmTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
        this.DataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
        this.DataGridView1.Columns[0].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
    }

    private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.CheckBox1.Checked) {
            this.DataGridView1.Columns[0].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
        } else {
            this.DataGridView1.Columns[0].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
        }
        this.DataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
}
```

1/ After loading the form:

[image]

2/ Allow sorting by clicking the checkbox:

[image]

3/ After clicking the column:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For set the the align in column header or in cell content you can use the IDE and open this property mask of dataGridView.

Set the align cell content in `Colunm` property or set the row header aling in `RowHeaderDefaultCellStyle`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView2.Columns){
    col.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable; // This first set it work
    col.HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    col.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
}
```